# A summation involving multinomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations, multinomial-coefficients

We need to find out

$$\sum {\binom{N}{a_1,a_2,a_3...a_B} a_1^{\alpha}a_2^{\alpha}...a_C^{\alpha} }$$

$$a_1+a_2...a_B=N, \alpha>0 ,0\lt C \le B$$

All are nonnegative integers.

We need to sum for all $a_i$. $N$,$B$ and $C$ are constants.

I was wondering if a closed form or a recurrence exists. I tried to solve it and failed miserably. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're summing over? Maybe tell us what you're trying to achieve,  and show us what you've done so far.

Comment: @DrXorile As specified in the question, we need to sum for all non negative $a_i$ such that sum till $a_B$ is $N$

Comment: So the $a_i$ are allowed to be equal to each other, and are not ordered or anything.

Comment: @DrXorile Yes. ­

Comment: For $\alpha = 1$ it is $B^{N-C} \frac{N!}{(N-C)!}$

Answer (score 0):

The summation is difficult while finding all permutation of $a's$. For a similiar problem I found the Equation-15 useful in following paper:

https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf

The sum is converted to simple incremental variable and product of binomial coefficients. Hope it would help you too.

Comment: Could you explain your approach? Like what would you do with $\prod a_i ^ \alpha$

Answer (score 0):

The sum:

$$
\sum_{a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb + a_B = N}
   \binom{N}{a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_B} x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2} \dotsm x_B^{a_B}
  = (x_1 + x_2 + \dotsm + x_B)^N
$$

Note that if $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, then:

$$
z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} A(z)
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n
$$

Doing this operation $\alpha$ times for each $x_i$, and setting $x_1 = x_2 = \dotsb = x_B = 1$ in the result gives your sum Ain't pretty...